# Получить текущую дату и прибавить к произвольной дате несколько дней

Tags: php

**1)** необходимо вывести текущую дату в таком формате: 24.03.2016

**2)** ещё необходимо взять такую дату например:

```
$date = '10.03.2016';
```

и прибавить к ней например 30 дней, что бы вышло так:

```
echo $date; //Ответ: 09.04.2016
```

Совсем запутался, не знаю как это всё сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: echo date("d.m.Y"); //текущую дату догадался как получить) а вот плюсовать в таком формате как n количество дней пока не знаю. дальше мне надо значение 23.10.2016 занести в базу данных в виде строки. а потом извлеь в любое удобное время, плюсануть несколько дней, и обратно записать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Форматировать дату можно при помощи функции date(), которая вторым аргументом она принимает дату и время, если не указать - будет текущая

```
echo date('d.m.Y');
```

Для того, чтобы прибавить к текущей дате 10 дней можно воспользоваться функцией strtotime()

```
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime("+10 days"));
```

Если вам требуется прибавить к строке '21.11.2015' десять дней, можно учесть, что strtotime() возвращает время в секундах с 1 января 1970 года и просто прибавить количество секунд, соответствующее 10 дням

```
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime('21.11.2015') + 10 * 24 * 3600);
```

Comment: Как к текущей прибавлять я теперь понял, спасибо. А как быть если есть в базе строка например 21.11.2015, как к такой строке прибавить  эти самые 10 дней? Суть в том, что я получил с помощью date('d.m.Y'); что хотел, и занёс в базу эту дату. А через несколько дней надо достать уже строку эту получается и плюсануть 10 дней

Comment: перевести строку в дату и прибавить 10 дней

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите перевести строку в дату, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с датами в PHP есть встроенный класс [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.construct.php). Даты можно [выводить в любом формате](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php), [добавлять интервалы](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php).

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

$date = new DateTime('21.11.2015');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
// "P" от "period", "30D" 30 days (дней)
echo $date->format('j.m.Y') . "\n";
// выведет: 21.12.2015
```